# How to search and replace in mongoose?

Tags: regex, node.js, mongoose

My objective :I want to update multiple documents in a collection in a certain path with a condition that path matches a regex then search and replace with certain value in the path then finally save all those documents persistently in db.

example:

```
myCollection : [
{ doc1 : { summary : 'Summary 1 : one', value : 1 },
{ doc2 : { summary : 'Summaryyuist 2 : two', value : 1 },
{ doc3 : { summary : 'hello 3 : three', value : 3 },
];
```

now i want to replace all 'Summary' with 'hello' in path :'summary'

so the result after query should be :

```
myCollection : [
{ doc1 : { summary : 'hello 1 : one', value : 1 },
{ doc2 : { summary : 'helloyuist 2 : two', value : 1 },
{ doc3 : { summary : 'hello 3 : three', value : 3 },
];
```

I am just looking the query to be used above.

From here 
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-regex

I found no information how to implement. Specially what the 'Number' parameter does in regex method.?

Also from here :

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-regex
Also i do not found the 'show code' link for monsoose regex. Can someone at least reply a link for mongoose regex code.

i find only how to find models, NOT how to update with replacement with a value that matches the regex in certain path of docs.

How to achieve my objective?

Comment: `regex` examples: `MyModel.where('summary').reqex(/Sum/).exec(console.log)` OR `MyModel.regex('summary', /Sum/).exec(console.log)` Second param is regular expression (not a number)

Comment: its written on above link, that second parameter is of type number

Comment: what arguments i will get in exec callback??

Comment: callback = function(err, results) {...}

Comment: https://github.com/aheckmann/mquery/blob/master/lib/mquery.js#L505 Document may not correct because yhey have the same document for a many method `gt` `gte` `lt` `lte` `ne` `in` `nin` `all` `regex`

Comment: then what should i do to update all the 'results' document in one go. So that for each model i fetch 'summary' field, find if the summary of doc matches regex and if so update it with new value and then save each document??

Comment: Just want to know.. whether results will be an array.. ( for which i will loop though all the models in array the update and save one by one.. that will be very costly as it will include many db queries ) OR results is a single model ( in which i write code for update and save model.. and that will be applicable internally to all the models which satisfied with where conditions.)

Comment: All update operator here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/ As you see, there are no repalce feature (?)

Comment: you want to say that 'results' will be an array and i have to loop though the 'results'. Isn't it very costly as it would need to execute many queries.?

Answer (score 0):

You could use mongoose Model.Update option i hope.

```
Model.update = function (query, doc, options, callback) { ... }
```

Example :

```
MyModel.update({ age: { $gt: 18 } }, { oldEnough: true }, fn);
MyModel.update({ name: 'Tobi' }, { ferret: true }, { multi: true }, function(err,numberAffected,   raw) {
 if (err) return handleError(err);
 console.log('The number of updated documents was %d', numberAffected);
 console.log('The raw response from Mongo was ', raw);
 });
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.update

Comment: How to i find what to replace with ??? { ferret: true } is replacing the whole value of doc path 'ferret'. I only want to replace the PARTIAL value from the path 'ferret', [considering value should be string.]

Comment: You can read the example like this-> Update oldenough : true for all the docuements where age elemetn greater than 18. You have condition and update field. If you want to update a inner element use driving.oldenough : true or drinking.oldenough :false.

Comment: please go through my edit. i don't want to replace the whole value from  path 'summary'. I only want to replace only 'Summary' from the whole value from path 'summary'

Comment: Unfortunately, MongoDB currently does not allow you to reference the existing value of any field when performing an update(). There is an existing Jira ticket to add this functionality.